# Confusion about Transposition Tables (chess programming)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chess

I'm currently using transposition tables for move ordering. Using iterative deepening search, I store the minimax value of the previous iteration to order moves for the next iteration. That's all fine and good.

Here's my confusion:

If I find a certain position in my transposition table, then I use the previously calculated score for move ordering (from the previous iteration of iterative deepening). However, if this position's score is updated (after minimax is returned), and the position is found AGAIN in another subtree (the same iteration of iterative deepening) - I don't want to just use it for move ordering... I should be able to return the value, because the value has now been calculated for this iteration and is absolute.

Here's my question: Is it standard to have two transposition tables? One for the previous iteration, and one for the current iteration of iterative deepening. So I would first check the table for the current iteration, to see if the minimax value was calculated already, and simply return this value. If it's not in this table, I would use the table for the previous iteration, for move ordering. If it's in neither, then it's a new position I haven't seen before in this search.

Is this line of thinking correct, or is there a more efficient method?

Comment: This question is going to be too broad/opinion based.  I would say it's worth a try using two.  If it helps you get more ply in less time then it's gravy.  If it doesn't then toss it.  There used to be a newsgroup for chess programmers.  Maybe try to track it down and ask there.  This just isn't the place for this kind of question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Dennis_Soemers. You should save depth and maybe even alpha/beta bounds added to your transposition table. No, you should not need two tables.

Let's examine the Stockfish source code on the table.

https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/master/src/tt.h

```
/// TTEntry struct is the 10 bytes transposition table entry, defined as below:
///
/// key        16 bit
/// move       16 bit
/// value      16 bit
/// eval value 16 bit
/// generation  6 bit
/// bound type  2 bit
/// depth       8 bit
```

The save function for the table is defined as:

```
void save(Key k, Value v, Bound b, Depth d, Move m, Value ev, uint8_t g)
```

Now, if you have two identical positions, from depth `d-1` and `d`. You can do something like:

```
// My hash key is now position + depth
Key my_hash_key = k + d
```

You can easily examine the previous iteration and the current iteration:

```
Key previous_iter_key = my_position_key + d-1
probe(previous_iter_key ...)

Key current_iter_key = my_position_key + d
probe(current_iter_key ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Typically you'd want to not only store the last found minimax value of a state in your table, but also the depth limit you used in the iteration when you stored the state in the table. That way, when you look it up in the table later, you can tell whether it was last updated in a previous iteration or in the current iteration by comparing the depth limit stored in the table entry to your current depth limit. If those are equal, you know the table entry was last updated in the current iteration, and you can directly use the value stored in the table without any extra search